# Nginx Vhost conflicting each other

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I wanted to use nginx as reverse proxy for the following sub domains `api.example.com` and `monitor.example.com` but the config settings of `api.example.com` is always overriding `monitor.example.com` . The api vhost has rate limiter and I don't want to apply that setting on monitor vhost.. `access_log` and `access_log` path are also not followed on the second vhost settings..

I can access the content of the backend servers properly but I don't understand why the config settings of `api.example.com` is also applied to `monitor.example.com` vhost.

**api.example.com**

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=api:10m rate=90r/m;

log_format custom '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
'"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
'"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$request_body"';

upstream backend  {
   server web-06:80 max_fails=5  fail_timeout=20s;
   server web-01:80 max_fails=5  fail_timeout=20s;
}


server {
  listen 80;
  #logging
  #access_log off;
  #error_log off;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log custom;

  location / {
    #rate limiting
    limit_req zone=api burst=1;

    proxy_pass  http://backend;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    client_max_body_size 10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_send_timeout 90;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;

    proxy_buffer_size 4k;
    proxy_buffers 4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
  }
}
```

**monitor.example.com**

```
upstream backend2  {
   server web-06:80 max_fails=5  fail_timeout=20s;
   server web-01:80 max_fails=5  fail_timeout=20s;
}


server {
  listen 80;
  #logging
  #access_log off;
  #error_log off;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/monitor-error.log;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/monitor.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://backend2;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure those are your actual `server` blocks? There seems to be stuff missing. If you deleted anything, put it back in.

Comment: yes those are the actual server blocks.. I can access the servers (web-01 and web-06) content via the reverse proxy using those sub domain it just that I don't understand why the nginx rate limit is also applied to the second vhost and when I access the second vhost it is writing logs to `/var/log/nginx/access.log`

Comment: If you have not removed anything, then where is your `server_name`?

Comment: There is no `server_name` on my reverse proxy config.. I think that is the lacking piece why they are overriding each other..

By the way this is how I configure my back-end servers for 


[api.example.com](https://gist.github.com/romelemperado/7ae18bacbe73739f54252647cf46dca0)  [monitor.example.com](https://gist.github.com/romelemperado/bba6e202b5cb80d9bb460e6462763d74)

Comment: You are right.. It is now working plus I added `proxy_set_header Host $host;`  under location block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your two server blocks will always conflict such that the *first observed server block in the configuration file will be taking precedent as the default server block for all requests*, unless you specify a proper `server_name` for each config to apply to incoming requests for that hostname / subdomain.  (This applies also for all requests of which a requested `$HOST` does not match any of the configurations provided, and there is not a `default_server` specified in the configurations).  This is how NGINX handles requests by default when there are missing configuration on server blocks, or with unmatched `$HOST` requests.

NGINX will check what hostname is requested.  If `$HOST` matches a server block with a matching `server_name` it will use that config for determining what to serve for the request.  Without such configuration to define what server block handles what, the first config block loaded in the configuration will be used by default when there is no matching `server_name` (and you didn't specify a `default_server`).  (`server_name api.example.com;` will specify the server block will match for `api.example.com`, while `server_name monitor.example.com;` specifies the server block that matches for `monitor.example.com`)

Proper reverse proxying of multiple backends by multiple host names through one NGINX instance can only be achieved this way, where each proxy block for handling different hostname requests to different backends has individually defined `server_name` directives for each `server` block.

Your backends will also have different configurations - if each backend only serves for that one host then you don't *need* to specify the server_name there - you *do need* to specify the server_name on the reverse proxy however to make sure it routes requests through the proper config blocks and then the proper backend.  (However, similar configuration may be needed on the backends if they can serve both sites)

<sub>I have set up many systems in which one NGINX instance reverse proxies to multiple different backends and systems on a network, and they have always needed `server_name` to be defined to properly work. This is also the same rationale for getting one NGINX instance to serve many different websites from the same instance and configuration files.  I also maintain the `nginx` package in Ubuntu, and this is a common issue I see brought up by people there when they set up their NGINX to do what you are trying to do.</sub>

Comment: You are right.. It is now working plus I added `proxy_set_header Host $host;`  under location block

Answer (score 2):

```
http{
...
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  api.example.com;
    #charset koi8-r;
    access_log  logs/api.example.com.access.log  combined;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass   http://servername1;
            root  path1;
    }

}
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name  monitor.example.com;
    access_log  logs/monitor.example.com.access.log  combined;
    location / {
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass   http://servername2;
            root path2;
    }   
}
```

}